# Does a public static const variable break the encapsulation ideology?

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I always seem to struggle with the decision of whether a value in a class which should be `static` and `const` should be public or private with a static public method for access.

```
class DeepThought
{
public:
    static const int TheAnswer = 42;
};
```

versus:

```
class DeepThought
{
public:
    static int GetTheAnswer() { return TheAnswer; }
private:
    static const int TheAnswer = 42;
};
```

I **want** to do it the first way, but somewhere deep inside me feels like it breaks encapsulation even though its a constant value. The second way just seems like it doesn't really add anything to the table though and needlessly clutters up the code.

So I ask, is there anything fundamentally wrong with either choice and if so, what?

Comment: I've actually never, ever had the need to do either in real code. Do you have a real world use-case for this?

Comment: @unapersson: You've never had a constant associated with a class?

Comment: Just thinking about how C# does it, any constant primitive types are all implicitly static as well. They occur all the time to allow you to associate what could easily be a global constant, but instead of being global, you are associating it with a class it logically belongs with.

Comment: @oli Yes, but not a static one.

Comment: The real question is why are you exposing the variable (at even through a getter). The answer of does it break encapsulation really depends on what is the meaning of the value.

Comment: @unapersson: there are some in the standard libraries, though, in template `numeric_limits`. I would think that counts as a real-world use-case. Unfortunately for the questioner, it uses both objects and functions for different values that in a given implementation actually are constant, so it doesn't provide much guidance.

Comment: @steve OK, when I start writing standard library implementations, I'll bear that in mind :-)

Comment: @unapersson: you haven't lived until you've at least implemented a chunk of Posix. `numeric_limits` in particular, I'll grant you, generally only needs implementing at most once per compiler port, but when writing traits class templates I tend to look to the standard for design tips. Actually, though, in non-template classes it's not a bad idea to use the enum trick instead, because the C++03 conditions for when a static const int data member is "used" (and hence requires a definition) and when it isn't are a pig.

Comment: @Steve whenever I see the word "number" I shudder and remember my A-level maths grade (too embarrassing to specify). I like to think of computer programs as happy, clappy shapes floating in some platonic dream world!

Comment: @unapersson: whereas I have a master's degree in maths, so that's exactly how I think of *numbers* ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a purely theoretical sense, the second option is the more correct. In the practical sense, I agree with you - wrapping the constant value with a getter function is useless and will be removed by the compiler anyway.

In my experience, sometimes the simpler approach is better, even if it violates OOP somewhat.

And a final note - we used to use enums for this:

```
enum CONSTS
{
    TheAnswer = 42,
};
```

Comment: If you ever have to change it, the compiler will be sure to give you lots of errors.

Comment: @Omnifarous: as will your customer's linker, since you've broken binary compatibility. Of course if you're not shipping library binaries, then you don't care about that.

Answer (score 6):

They aren't semantically equivalent. Prefer the first, because it yields an integral constant expression which can be used in array bounds, nontype template arguments, case expressions, etc.

```
int a[DeepThought::TheAnswer];      // ok
int b[DeepThought::GetTheAnswer()]; // broken
```

Comment: +1: Exactly! static integral const have a well defined and important role in C++.

Comment: I agree. But in C++0x functions can also be marked as returning a const expression and thus used at compile time for array bounds. This does not change my minds that I prefer the first method.

Comment: I boggle every time someone blithely assumes C++0x.  The code I work on, we can't even assume C++98.  (For instance: last I heard, the Android NDK doesn't include most of the C++ standard library.)

Answer (score 4):

You should think about *why* the OOP "ideology" says don't expose variables, only getters.  The usual argument is because you might, at some point in the future, need to make access to that variable do something more complicated.  But the odds of this are small to begin with, and become even smaller when you're talking about a *constant*.

I would go ahead and expose the constant as a constant.  But then I would also usually go ahead and expose variables when there is no *current* need for a getter.  The Python crew would call this an application of the [You Aren't Gonna Need It](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html) principle.

Answer (score 2):

There is the obvious:

```
class DeepThought
{
public:
    static int GetTheAnswer() { return 42; }
};
```

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking as well.

Answer (score 2):

You may as well use the first. Consider- what logic are you going to put in to `GetTheAnswer()`? You can't change it's signature or the fact that it's static without breaking it's interface considerations. This means that unless you're going to start making non-constant global variables, which would be Extremely Bad™, there's nothing you might put in `GetTheAnswer()` that you can't put in the constexpr which `TheAnswer` is assigned to.

Moreover, there are limits with what you can do with `GetTheAnswer()`, for example, in the first you could take the address of the constant and with `GetTheAnswer()`, you can't, even though it's pretty reasonable that you should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

these constants like this are basically hidden singleton pattern. There is only one instance of the constants available. This will be the normal evolution of such code:

```
class DeepThought {
public:
   static const int i=10;
   void f() { std::cout << i; }
};
```

Then you'll want to change the variable to change on runtime, it'll become like this:

```
   class Singleton {
      static Singleton &get() { static Singleton s; return s; }
      int get_i() const { return i; }
   };
   class DeepThought {
   public:
     void f() { std::cout << Singleton::get().get_i(); }
   };
```

Then at some point you'll want more than one instance of the constant and it'll become like this:

```
  struct Data
  {
     int i;
  };
  class DeepThought {
  public:
    DeepThought(Data &d) : d(d) { }
    void f() { std::cout << d.i; }
  private:
    Data &d;
  };
  int main() { Data d; DeepThought dt(d); dt.f(); }
```

During the evolution of the code, it'll change quite much and if you have large amount of code like that, doing the changes could take large amount of effort.