# Does static constants violate "encapsulation"?

Tags: java, encapsulation

Ok so I'm using this book: Core Java Volume I--Fundamentals.

It defines encapsulation as follows:

> Encapsulation (sometimes called information hiding) is a key concept
> in working with objects. Formally, encapsulation is simply combining
> data and behavior in one package and hiding the implementation details
> from the users of the object.

From searching in SO, I know that that encapsulation and information hiding are separate concepts but used in conjunction. But, let's stick to the book's definition(which says encapsulation==implementation-hiding) for the sake of this question as this question uses the book's examples.

```
public class Math
{
 . . .
 public static final double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
 . . .
}
```

The book says this doesn't break encapsulation as its a constant. But doesn't the above code break the **implementation hiding** part of encapsulation(by the book's definition) since PI is visible to not only class but rest of program.

My question is actually a possible duplicate of this: [Does a public static const variable break the encapsulation ideology?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5922455/13748491) (tagged with C++ though) but the answer says that it does violate encapsulation(contradictory to the book) and that's ok. I understand if my question is closed because of this possible duplicate

Edit: I'll just post another example code as a comment mentioned PI isn't considered an implementation detail

```
public class System
{
 . . .
 public static final PrintStream out = . . .;
 . . .
}
```

Comment: Pi is a constant. There is no implementation to hide.

Comment: Isn't implementation just information? So then isn't the information PI not hidden anymore?

Comment: In that second case: Yes, it violates encapsulation and you generally should avoid using constants except for things that just are, by definition, constant.

Comment: @Taschi so it's acceptable to break encapsulation then? The book said it's fine since its value can't be changed. But isn't encapsulation like some principle we have to adhere to in OOP(im a newbie, i may be wrong)?

Comment: @Taschi Sorry I realised that I'm now asking a totally different question. I will do a separate post

Comment: No, implementation isn't just information. It is technique. For example there are several formulas for Pi, and if one of those had been used it would be proper to hide it behind a functional interface. But as it is also one of the best-known constants in the universe, taught in third grade, there is no reason to conceal it.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Ahh I see, so this means that the 2nd example shouldn't violate encapsulation too

Comment: It doesn't 'mean' any such thing. I cannot follow your thought process. A constant of the universe has nothing to do with a `PrintStream`.

Comment: Sorry I got confused, 2nd example does break encapsulation then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question. I don't think the examples you provided break encapsulation, at least not strictly.

The first example you gave is the constant PI and the second is an example that provides access to the out constant in System; presumably to make use of some code such as `System.out.println("HelloWorld!");`. As others have already mentioned, `PI` is effectively just a constant and users of the constant have no means by which to modify or influence the value. Users of `PI` still need to reference the constant (which constitutes the API here) in their code. If `PI` were modified (unlikely, but who knows) users would be safe from the implication of that change because they'd be required to recompile the code anyways.

A helpful way to think about encapsulation is to think about what would be required in order to violate encapsulation. Effective Java 3rd edition describes this well in Item 16, suggesting that without proper encapsulation "you can't change the representation without changing the API, you can't enforce invariants, and you can't take auxiliary action when a field is accessed."

A very clear violation of the above would be the following class (also in Item 16 of Effective Java):

```
class Point {
  public double x;
  public double y;
}
```

All fields are public and users of this API would be forced to use the fields directly. If later the author decided to add some validation checking before `x` or `y` could be accessed or modified then it would be impossible to do so without potentially breaking existing clients. The API would have to be significantly modified and likely breaking the behavior of users downstream.

Now let's look at the second example you provided:

```
public class System
{
 . . .
 public static final PrintStream out = . . .;
 . . .
}
```

This seems very similar to the example of `PI` above but there's a key difference: the field in question is a PrintStream. While the `out` field itself is a clear part of this API that may now be hard to change (now that it's exposed clients are going to use and rely on it), the `PrintStream` type is a class that is actually what's interesting here: users will be referencing methods on the class. Here we have the key functionality within the API of `PrintStream` which can be evolved over time without breaking usage. It's also possible in the future to have the `out` constant changed out to refer to a different `PrintStream` subclass and users of the API should be unaffected.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry for the later reply, what do you mean by clients, are they just stuff that interact with your class? Also, could you dumb the paragraph down for me: `"you can't change the representation without changing the API, you can't enforce invariants, and you can't take auxiliary action when a field is accessed." `. I'm having difficulty understanding that

Comment: But am I right to say that the main essence of your answer is that as long as the clients interacting with your class are not adversely impacted when the design of data/data itself is changed in the class , we are not breaking encapsulation, at least not strictly. But strictly, we are breaking encapsulation for the 2nd example

Comment: @HelloWorld I'd say you're right about the essence. Let me clarify in a way that will also answer your first question about reclarifying the quoted text. First of all, "clients" refers to any code that makes use of your code by calling/using the exposed API.

To rephrase the above: If you have designed your class in such a way that changes to the internal representation of the data and usage of that data can be done in a way that doesn't negatively affect current and future users of your code then you have achieved encapsulation. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: @HelloWorld I'd also not worry too much about what's "strictly" adhering to the definition. API design is a bit of an art and I'd rather be more concerned about how to design your code in a way that's easy to use (by others) and easy to change (by yourself) without negatively impacting other users. Sometimes the right design is in fact to use a class like the `Point` class I showed above so long as it's inaccessible to users (maybe in a package-private only class).

Answer (score 1):

Static literals are not part of any object, they're just data assigned to a global variable for convince.
Thus it's not a violation of encapsulation per se, but a complete lack of object orientation.
The OOP way is to not have a global constant at all, and define an object which addresses your problem.

```java
interface Figure {
    double perimeter();
}
class Circle implements Figure {
    private final double radius;

    @Override
    public double perimeter() {
        return this.radius * 2 * (float) 3.1416926; 
    }
}
```

Here is some more discussion on the topic:
https://www.yegor256.com/2015/07/06/public-static-literals.html

Comment: Well, Java doesn't allow you to have constants outside of classes, but you can have them in other languages that at least allow OO, like C++, Perl, Python.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think static comes under OOP principle. So it neither violates nor abides.